# Crystal Report, one to many relationship table

Tags: crystal-reports

I have four tables

```
- CONSUMPTION
- CONSUMPTION_EMPLOYEE
- CONSUMPTION_LOCATION
- CONSUMPTION_MATERIAL
```

and all tables related by field `CONSUMPTION_CODE`

Please have a look at http://s11.postimage.org/6e26fvc4z/table.gif

My goal is to generate report using crystal report to be similar like http://s8.postimage.org/u8lv1kv5x/image.gif

I can't find on the internet on how to generate multiple report on a single crystal report page, since I prefer not to use sub-report if possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a main report and two sub-reports.

- Main - consumption information group header 1 (group on consumption ID); employee information in the Details section
- Sub 0 - location information; add to group footer 1a
- Sub 1 - material information; add to group footer 1b (you will need to add a second group-footer section)